# Using Function.call(this, arg1) results in an undefined for this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Main App.jsx**

[image]

Function from a separate file

[image]

In the last line of the first picture, I'm attempting to call the function handleOnPageNavigation from another file using .call(). I want to pass in **this** into the function so I can change the state which should result in the page updating.

But upon clicking the item, the console states that *Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined*

I'm not sure I understand why **this** is considered undefine since I'm passing it in through .call(). Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please add code snippet instead of images

Comment: @chillbabe104 Did you Import handleOnPageNavigation method in app.jsx file?

Comment: @akshay1293 yes I did. If not, I think the console error might display the inability to find the function rather than this being undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used arrow function to define handleOnPageNavigation method and no matter what you pass in as execution context to it, it will ignore all of that and take the context in which it is defined. Make it into a normal function to take the execution context

```
function handleOnPageNavigation(item){
   this.setState({
      page: item.key
   })
}
export { handleOnPageNavigation };
```

> However, I must say that such kind of pattern are very difficult to
>   debug and hence you must always have functions that call setState
>   within the component itself and not outside of it

Comment: OP can use the useState hooks if he really want to update state from outside of component

Comment: @DhavalPatel, the question is related to class components. Also with Hooks you don't really update state from outside of component, instead you define Custom hooks that maintain their own state and provider handler to update state much like HOCs to the components that use them

Comment: that worked! thank you so much for the input. Would having some functions defined normally and others defined using the arrow be considered bad stylistically since it wouldn't be considered consistent?

Comment: ` Would having some functions defined normally and others defined using the arrow be considered bad stylistically since it wouldn't be considered consistent` Not really, it depends on your use case. Only functions that need context from the enclosing scope need to be written as arrow functions but you can still define the others as arrow functions as long as you need to use the enclosing context